# Adding a custom G-code to parse strings from `configuration.h` in Marlin 2.0.x

Tags: marlin, g-code

I'm working with Marlin 2.0.x firmware for a special device, I have added an extra axis to the firmware and it's working well, However, I'd like to implement a custom G-code command that can parse a group of strings I've defined in the `Configuration.h` file.

Specifically, I want to:

1. Define a group of strings, for example, `G** x** y**, G** z**, M**` (like a series of codes) within `Configuration.h`.
2. Add a new custom G-code command, let's call it `M9999`, which, when sent to the printer, would trigger the firmware to parse and use the values of the previously defined custom strings in some way.

I've explored various resources and attempted modifications, but I'm struggling with the exact steps and code changes required to achieve this functionality. Could someone please provide guidance on how to properly define these strings and implement the custom G-code command within Marlin 2.0.x?

I have already checked Macros in Marlin firmware, but macros need to be redefined every time I turn on the printer as they can't be saved in the firmware or in the EEPROM. I have found a way to add a new G-code in `gcode.c` however I don't know which function can parse a string, or where to add this function.

In `M810`-`M819`, I found `char * const cmd = gcode_macros[index]; if (strlen(cmd)) process_subcommands_now(cmd);`. Can I use the function `process_subcommands_now(cmd)` to parse and run a group of G-codes predefined in `configuration.h`?

Your expertise and advice on the necessary modifications and syntax would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll have better luck asking that question here: https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues.